# Vue.js - Element UI - get the state of form validation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

[image]

Steps to reproduce

The recurrence link is this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-vuejs-element-3kko7a

```
password input 2

username input 11

Change username to 2// should be able to submit, but not
```

**Expected:** formvalid = true

Validate Code here:

```
 checkForm() {
        // console.log('validate runs');
        // @ts-ignore
        const fields = this.$refs.ruleForm.fields;
        if (fields.find((f) => f.validateState === 'validating')) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.checkForm();
          }, 100);
        }
        this.formValid = fields.reduce((acc, f) => {
          const valid = (f.isRequired && f.validateState === 'success');
          const notErroring = (!f.isRequired && f.validateState !== 'error');
          return acc && (valid || notErroring);
        }, true);
        console.log('valid:', this.$data.formValid);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you watch `ruleForm` - so everytime `ruleForm` changes you trigger `checkform` - but your validtor triggers on `blur` after you set `ruleForm` so you first test then turn valid. change this into a getter:

```
get formValid(){

   const fields = this.$refs.ruleForm.fields || [];
    if (fields.find((f) => f.validateState === 'validating')) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.checkForm();
      }, 100);
    }
    return fields.reduce((acc, f) => {
      const valid = (f.isRequired && f.validateState === 'success');
      const notErroring = (!f.isRequired && f.validateState !== 'error');
      return acc && (valid || notErroring);
    }, fields.length > 0);
}
```

Comment: I edit some code, but stil not work , how to rewritte this.checkForm or call this getter method? 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-vuejs-element-amglzq

Comment: anyone here ?  any help?